# Combobox não retorna colunas do SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, delphi

No seguinte codigo, ele deveria me apresentar as colunas de uma tabela que tenho no meu sistema, porem ao clicar para exibir as opções no combobox não aparece nada.
Entretanto se eu começar a digitar o nome do campo por exemplo Nome_ ele completa com Nome_Rsocial e apresenta o resultado corretamente.

o codigo:

```
        cbbColunas.Items.Clear();
     with TADOQuery.Create(Self) do
         begin
     Connection := ADOConnection1; 
        SQL.Text := 'SELECT '+ ' c.name '+
         'FROM '+ ' Sys.Columns c '+
         'LEFT OUTER JOIN '+
         ' sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id '
        + 'LEFT OUTER JOIN '+
         ' sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id '
        + 'WHERE '+
         ' c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(:tabela)';
        Parameters.ParamByName('tabela').DataType := ftString; Parameters.ParamByName('tabela').Value := cbbTabelas.Text;
         Open();
         First(); 
        while not Eof do begin cbbColunas.Items.Add(FieldByName('name').AsString);
        Next(); 
        end; 
        end;
```

Comment: E este código apresentado esta sendo chamado onde ?

Comment: onchange do combobox

Comment: onde estou não posso rodar o Delphi, ali no where onde esta buscando pelo parâmetro, tenta usar um LIKE. Pergunta, precisa usar o parâmetro ?

Comment: Posso tentar com o Like, no almoço testo e retorno aqui

Comment: Não funcionou, o que me intriga é que se eu digitar algum texto no combo, as colunas aparecem, porem se eu clicar nelas elas nao preenchem o combo.

Comment: Resolvi colocando o codigo em onmouseenter, não é o certo mas resolve meu caso no momento.

Comment: Estranho, no chance já deveria funcionar! Mas que bom que achou uma solução!

Comment: Concordo plenamente, testei a versão do delphi testei em 2 diferente. e continuou..vou deixar ai talvez alguém me de uma luz.

Comment: O evento onchange é disparado quando você começa a digitar alguma coisa, não seria mais simples você utilizar um  DBComboBox com todos os dados já preenchidos?

Answer (score -1):

Utilize a função abaixo:

```
ADOConnection.GetFieldNames('NOME_DA_TABELA', cbbColunas.Items);
```